# Coding multiple count queries in mysql / php

Tags: php, mysql, count, echo

I am coding the following, Im still very new to php so my coding is a bit rubbish, is there a better way of doing the following, ideally putting into one query or something, as this is the only way I know how to do it :-S .
Thanks :-)

```
<?php
$query = ("SELECT COUNT(receivegasoilmailinglist) FROM     hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE      receivegasoilmailinglist='yes'"); 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
echo '<h1> gasoil :';
echo $row[0];  
echo '</h1>';
 ?>

<?php
$query2 = ("SELECT COUNT(receivedervmailinglist) FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivedervmailinglist='yes'"); 
 $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error()); 

 $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2); 
 echo '<h1> derv :';
 echo $row2[0];  
 echo '</h1>';
 ?>

<?php
 $query3 = ("SELECT COUNT(receivekeromailinglist) FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivekeromailinglist='yes'"); 
 $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error()); 

$row3 = mysql_fetch_row($result3); 
echo '<h1> kero :';
echo $row3[0];  
echo '</h1>';
?>
```

Comment: It is [officially recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) that you not use the mysql_* functions. Instead, one should use MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (and only if) either of these is true:

- most of the rows in hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead want some sort of newsletter
- there are no indices on the receive*mailinglist fields

you can save a lot of DB muscle by doing

```
SELECT 
  sum(if(receivegasoilmailinglist='yes',1,0)) AS gasoil,
  sum(if(receivedervmailinglist='yes',1,0)) AS derv,
  sum(if(receivekeromailinglist='yes',1,0)) AS kero
FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead;
```

as this will traverse the table only once.

For the rest of the job you use ofcourse

```
$sql="... as above ...";
$qry = mysql_query($sql) or die("Query failed: <br>SQL=$sql<br>Error=".mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_fetch_row($qry);
echo "<h1> gasoil: ".$qry[0]."</h1>";
echo "<h1> derv: ".$qry[1]."</h1>";
echo "<h1> kero: ".$qry[2]."</h1>";
```

Comment: Hi, that query in mysql returns gasoil  derv  kero
2  4  3 , but when I use it with the php in a page I just get - gasoil:
derv:
kero:

Comment: you need to run a while loop or some other way of fetching the results. You do this in your original post. while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){ ... }

Comment: This is because I am a moron. Fixed the PHP, should work now.

Comment: @KaiQing no need for a while, we return exactly 1 row.

Comment: yeah, no need for while but there WAS need to fetch row or any other fetch. the original response just tried to access the query var itself. A while loop may have not been efficient, but it would have worked.

Comment: @KaiQing forgetting the mysql_fetch_row() was what prompted me to call myself a moron. Consider me punished.

Comment: it happens. the fury of wanting to post as fast as possible to avoid that popup telling me there are 4 new answers and that I just wasted my time typing out an elaborate response identical to everyone elses... been there often.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UNION and set a type in each query then loop the three records all at once. UNION collates results together but must feature the same exact output structure.

```
$query = 
"SELECT 'gasoil' AS counttype, COUNT(receivegasoilmailinglist) AS countdata FROM     hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE      receivegasoilmailinglist='yes'
UNION
SELECT 'derv' AS counttype, COUNT(receivedervmailinglist) AS countdata FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivedervmailinglist='yes'
UNION
SELECT 'kero' AS counttype, COUNT(receivekeromailinglist) AS countdata FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivekeromailinglist='yes'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<h1> '.$row['counttype'].' :';
    echo $row['countdata'];  
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

And also, my code is much shorter for the exact same processing! :)

Comment: Hi, I just tried this but get a row of three : 's but thats it, it doesnt seem to be pulling any data out.

Comment: I seriously don't know why it is not working since i copy pasted your SQL queries... If you run the big query in PHPMyAdmin (or your favorite tool) does it return the expected data?

Comment: Yes that works in php my admin, I will check iv not made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I have had a look and cant see anything wrong, I have literally just wrapped it in php tags and thats it, it is echoing the colons and thats it, no errors either, yet if I run that query in phpmyadmin I get:

Comment: counttype  countdata
gasoil  2
derv  4
kero  3

Comment: So the data is fine, it's your php code that doesn't output the correct data... HAAAHAAAA, i see it, you used mysql_fetch_row originaly, i'll change my example to mysql_fetch_assoc...

Answer (score 0):

I would do a union personally.

```
$query = "(SELECT COUNT(receivegasoilmailinglist) AS gasoil FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivegasoilmailinglist='yes') UNION (SELECT COUNT(receivedervmailinglist) AS derv FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivedervmailinglist='yes') UNION (SELECT COUNT(receivekeromailinglist) AS kero FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE receivekeromailinglist='yes')";
```

and since others have answered I figure you can tell how to loop through the results.

If you are unsure about unions, you can run queries like this so long as each  expected result datatype is the same. In this case, they're all counts, so it should work well.